# Getting path to the desktop for current user in C using WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi

I'm very new to WinAPI programming. I was wondering how I could get the path of the user's Desktop and then print out the full path to the console. This is my current code:

```
TCHAR* path = 0;
HRESULT result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &path);
if (result == S_OK)
{
    printf("%s\n", path);
}
CoTaskMemFree(path)
```

It does find the path, but it prints out "C" for the path rather than the entire path with slashes. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: TCHAR is no benefit to you because you aren't supporting Windows 98. So use wchar_t and stick exclusively to the native Unicode API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints a single character because you tried to print a wide string as a narrow string. You probably have UNICODE/_UNICODE defined so TCHAR is WCHAR.

If you insist on using TCHAR you should use the correct printing function from tchar.h:

```
_tprintf(_T("%s\n"), path);
```

Otherwise you can use the wide version:

```
wprintf(L"%s\n", path);
```

Or the worst solution, convert the string to a narrow codepage string:

```
printf("%ls\n", path); // This might not display all Unicode characters correctly
```

Comment: Often you can add "A" to the end of a function name to pick the ASCII version but according to MSDN this is one of the win32 functions that only has a unicode version -- "_Out_ PWSTR  *ppszPath" so it's not an alias for SHGetKnownFolderPathW, that does not exist.

Comment: @DaveS Ah, yes, good point, I was thinking of the older special folder functions. Using the "A" version is not a good idea, it cannot handle all Unicode paths.

Comment: I believe `printf("%S\n", path);` is also an option?

Comment: `tchar` is intended for situations where the result will be `char` when `UNICODE` is not defined, and `wchar_t` when it is defined. That's not the case here, so `tchar` doesn't fit at all.

Comment: @zzxyz %S is the same as %ls in this case

Comment: @JerryCoffin UNICODE is defined because SHGetKnownFolderPath takes a wide string pointer. TCHAR must map to WCHAR for the OPs posted code to compile.

Comment: @Anders: That's my point: the whole point of TCHAR is to map to either char or wchar_t. In this case, you can't do that, so it shouldn't be using TCHAR at all. It should use wchar_t (or WCHAR) since it must always use wide characters to work.

Answer (score 3):

`SHGetKnownFolderPath()` outputs a `wchar_t*` pointer, not a `TCHAR*` pointer. There is no ANSI version of `SHGetKnownFolderPath()`, so you should not be using `TCHAR` at all in this situation. In fact, your code will not compile unless `UNICODE` is defined so `TCHAR` maps to `wchar_t`.

The reason you only see the 1st character is because you are passing a `wchar_t*` where a `char*` is expected.  On Windows, `wchar_t` is 16-bit, and so `wchar_t*` strings are encoded in UCS-2 or UTF-16LE.  All ASCII characters in UCS-2/UTF-16LE have their high 8 bits set to 0.  Your use of `printf()` is expecting a null terminated `char*` string, so the high 0x00 byte of the 1st `wchar_t` character gets misinterpreted as a null terminator.

To do what you want, you need to print out the returned path as-is as a wide string, not as a (misinterpreted) narrow string.

You could use `%S` with `printf()`, eg:

```
PWSTR path;
if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &path) == S_OK)
{
    printf("%S\n", path);
    CoTaskMemFree(path);
}
```

But this is not portable across compilers. You should use `%s` with `wprintf()` instead:

```
PWSTR path;
if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(&FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &path) == S_OK)
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", path);
    CoTaskMemFree(path);
}
```